# Como excluir linhas de um Data Frame em R baseado nos valores de uma das colunas?

Tags: r, data.frame

Eu quero excluir as linhas que tenham um determinado valor numa coluna.

vamos supor que tenho um DF onde a primeira coluna é um indice com letras do alfabeto, mas, não sei a posição, quero que as linhas com indice vogal sejam removidas como faço.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Brasil! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu entendi depois que eu poderia apenas fazer uma reatribuição sobre a variável que continha meu Data Frame forçando que obedecesse às condições que eu desejava.

Neste caso a "perfil" é uma variável com o valor que quero resgatar.

```
df <- df[df$Perfil.do.entrevistado==perfil,]
```

Assim ele atribui todos que a linha tivesse o valor desejado e os outros são automaticamente descartados.

Answer (score 5):

Para pesquisar padrões alfanuméricos, o melhor é usar o `grep` ou `grepl`.

```
set.seed(6323)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis

n <- 100
DF <- data.frame(A = sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), X = rnorm(n))

inx <- grepl("[AEIOU]", toupper(DF[[1]]))

DF2 <- DF[!inx, ]        # Usando um indíce lógico
DF3 <- subset(DF, !inx)  # Usando avaliação não-standard

identical(DF2, DF3)
#[1] TRUE

head(DF2)
#  A           X
#2 F -0.54113708
#3 D -0.72646708
#4 V  0.02213349
#6 X -0.64141533
#7 F -1.06416864
#8 Y -0.90681239
```

Outra maneira equivalente será com `%in%`.

```
inx2 <- toupper(DF[[1]]) %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
DF4 <- DF[!inx2, ]        # Usando um indíce lógico mais uma vez

identical(DF2, DF4)
#[1] TRUE
```